# html form array for each update into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have been racking my brains trying to figure this out for days and have come up short. I am trying to update rows in the database with the following form value:

```
<input type="text" name="item[]" maxlength="255" value="',htmlentities($item["item"]),'">
<input type="text" name="description[]" maxlength="255" value="',htmlentities($item["description"]),'">
<input type="text" name="rate[]" maxlength="10" value="',htmlentities($item["rate"]),'">
<input type="hidden" name="itemid[]" value="',htmlentities($item["id"]),'" />
```

This following array back:

```
Array
(
[item] => Array
    (
        [0] => item listing 1
        [1] => item listing 2
    )

[description] => Array
    (
        [0] => item testing description
        [1] => item testing description
    )

[rate] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1.00
        [1] => 2.00
    )

[itemid] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )
)
```

Now im trying to update into a database with the following but to no avail I can only update the last row of fields (the [1] values) :( any help would be great

```
if (is_array($values))
{
for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++)
{
    $item           = $values['item'];
    $description    = $values['description'];
    $rate           = $values['rate'];
    $id             = $values['itemid'];

    // $query = "UPDATE `invoice_items` SET `item` = '{$item}', `description` = '{$description}', `rate` = '{$rate}' WHERE `id` = '{$id}';";
    // Setting query function here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add sub-array numbers too.

```
if (is_array($values))
{
for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++)
{
    $item           = $values['item'][$i];
    $description    = $values['description'][$i];
    $rate           = $values['rate'][$i];
    $id             = $values['itemid'][$i];

    // $query = "UPDATE `invoice_items` SET `item` = '{$item}', `description` = '{$description}', `rate` = '{$rate}' WHERE `id` = '{$id}';";
    // Setting query function here
}
```

Comment: yep, that should do. you could use php's `foreach` as well

Comment: thanks works like a charm... very quick response to., very impressed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
if (is_array($values)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($values['itemid']); $i++) {
        $item           = $values['item'][$i];
        $description    = $values['description'][$i];
        $rate           = $values['rate'][$i];
        $id             = $values['itemid'][$i];

        $query = "UPDATE `invoice_items` SET `item` = '{$item}', `description` = '{$description}', `rate` = '{$rate}' WHERE `id` = '{$id}';";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```